# Highstock: Data Grouping undesired behavior on right-most point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm experiencing some undesired behavior when using the built in data-grouping for Highstock charts. The result appears to be some sort of conflict between the underlying data-grouping logic (only grouping visible points?) and the extremes/navigator.

Some context:
I have a chart where the data points occur roughly every 2 minutes. Aside from viewing the point individually the user has the option to select a number of different groupings for the data points (15 minute intervals, hourly, and daily). The options for this are:

```
const dataGrouping = {
  enabled: true,
  forced: true,
  approximation: 'sum',
  units: [['minute', [15]]]
};
```

Where the units would be swapped out depending on which option was selected. This appears to be working as intended. Depending on which grouping the user has selected I now enforce restrictions on the navigator to snap to the nearest acceptable interval. For example, for the 15 minute interval:

```
const newMin = moment(extremes.min).minute(15 * Math.round(moment(extremes.min).startOf('minute').minute() / 15)).startOf('minute').valueOf();

let newMax = moment(extremes.max).minute(15 * Math.round(moment(extremes.max).startOf('minute').minute() / 15)).startOf('minute').valueOf() - 1000;

if (newMax > extremes.dataMax) {
  newMax = extremes.dataMax;
}

if (newMin !== extremes.min || newMax !== extremes.max) {
  this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(newMin, newMax, true, true, { trigger: 'adjExtremes' });
}
```

This also appears to be working as expected with one small flaw: the right-most point on the graph trails off incorrectly. For instance, if the right-most point is at 3:00PM and meant to be an aggregation of the values between 3:00PM and 3:15PM the 3:00PM point will only sum any points between 3:00PM and 3:01PM as 3:01 - 3:15 are not technically visible on the graph (however the data is there, just not in the visible range).

[Bad Right-Most Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiONh.png)

I've tried a number of different things to no avail. Subtracting a second off of the max extreme makes it so the point is no longer there, and therefore can't show an incorrect value on hover, however the line still trails off the to bottom. I believe that given the nature of the issue, no matter what I set the extreme to I will continue to have the problem. The Highstock demo example for Data Grouping doesn't appear to have this issue (points right on the line can be seen going up, even when the point/group isn't drawn on the graph).

My thought is that the correct solution to this would be to force Highstock to group points so long as the data exists, even if the points wouldn't technically be drawn on screen. I've tried turning off the various thresholds, but that also has no effect.

Comment: So summarizing,  the problem is that the grouping groups only the visible points? https://jsfiddle.net/Lpdubhv1/ Edit the jsfiddle if it something different. If the problem is as in the fiddle, then you would probably have to group the data on your own - by creating multiple series, grouped manually